# DefaultHttpClient cancel connection to server

Tags: java, connection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a DefaultHttpClient provided by Apache, and I create and execute different requests.

The problem is that connection to server may be establishing for a quite long time, and user of my program may want to cancel this process.

**Is there any valid way to abort connection establishing on demand?**

*(I can't use request.abort() because it executes after httpClient.execute(request), which seems to be the bottleneck here. There is also no way for me to use setConnectionTimeout because I have no idea when user will cancel the request)*

I've already tried wrapping request execution in separate thread, and interrupting it on user cancellation event, but I believe I can find better solution.

Also I think of using HttpAsyncClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood there is no way to cancel the request without wrapping it into other thread.
I used HttpAsyncClient instead, which provides you with `Future` Object, which has `cancel` method.